# Android studio Add markers to google maps from Parse database

Tags: java, android, google-maps, parse-platform

Newbie learning to write code in Android studio with 4 weeks of basic online courses from treehouse and Udemy.  I appreciate this community a lot for learning how to solve common problems from experienced mentors in this field. So any assistance will be reciprocated when I am able to give back to the community.  Thanks for your time.

Like to learn if Android studio can add markers to google maps from Parse database with Geopoint Query class Location object "location, geopointLocation"  E.g 10+ markers locations with the forloop function to display all objects geopoint.

Have noticed on Parse documentation that geopoint query's are not supported and the link to anywall Parse tutorial is promoted, however the anywall code is not clear to me for my beginner level if this function is even possible with only 1 not many markers shown on a map in the parse anywall example.  On a side note. Does anyone know why geopoint and other functions are not supported ?  "http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/#CompoundQueries 
other then the sudden shut down shock, thanks to $&#^$*%....

Hopefully, this will spark a conversation into the Pros and negatives with using Parse and if there are better alternatives out there with similar functions and dashboard display.  Does anyone else think it was unfair to shut down a successful company?  what will be the flow on effects?

Appreciate any tips, links, books suggestion and/or tutorials to learn more about Parse and Android studio to test this on an app.   Thanks for your time and patience in answering a newbie query.  Hopefully this function is possible with parse? if so, is there user guides available online that go into finer detail.

Answer (score 0):

> Found the solution guys - Keep me posted if that help you too.  First
>   post given back to the community. Thanks
>
> ```
> ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("YourClass");
> ParseGeoPoint geoPointLocation = new ParseGeoPoint();
> query.whereNear("YourColumn", geoPointLocation);
>     query.include("name");
>     query.setLimit(100);
>     Log.i("stevemelblog", "query 1 hundred");
>     query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
>         @Override
>         public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
>             if (e == null) {
>                 Log.i("stevemelblog", "e equal null");
>             }
>
>             if (objects.size() > 0) {
>                 for (ParseObject object : objects) {
>                     //This is the loop function //Log.i("stevemelblog", "looked for objects");
>                     ParseGeoPoint point = object.getParseGeoPoint("YourColumn");
>                     Double lat = point.getLatitude();
>                     Double log = point.getLongitude();
>
>                     ParseObject name = object.getParseObject("YourClass");
>
>                     LatLng marker = new LatLng(lat, log);
>                     Log.i("stevelog", "Latitude :" + lat + " Longitude: " + log);
>
>
>                     mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>                             .title("Your made it here, where next ")
>                             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.iconulike))
>                             //.infoWindowAnchor(0.5f, 0.5f)                                //.snippet("You can and will achieve")
>                             .position(marker)); 
>
>
>                     if (marker1 == null) {
>                         marker1 = mMap.addMarker(address);
>                     } else if (marker2 == null) {
>                         marker2 = mMap.addMarker();
>                         drawLline();
>
>                     } else {
>                         removeAll();
>                         marker1 = mMap.addMarker();
>                     }
>
>                     mMap.moveCamera();
>
>
>                 }
>
>
>             }
>         }
>     });
>
> }
> ```